# Syntax to instantiate a nested dictionary with a compare parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, syntax

How should I instantiate a nested dictionary with a compare parameter?
I can create a single dictionary, but I am unsure how to pas the param when nested.

```
var single = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ulong>(new ByteArrayComparer());

//Where do I put ByteArrayComparer?
var nested = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ulong>>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to specify it in each dictionary you use as a value for an entry in the "outer" dictionary. It's entirely possible for different values to use different comparers:

```cs
var nested = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ulong>>
{
    { 123UL, new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ulong>(new ByteArrayComparer()) },
    { 456UL, new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], ulong>(new OtherComparer()) },
};
```